# Spring boot search a word in all columns

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a table `User`. A `User` entity has `firstName`, `LastName`, `middleName`. I want to get all rows that contain a word `loe` (`LIKE %loe%`) in one of these columns. I believe it narrow downs to :

```
Page<User> findBy<columnName>Or<ColumnName>Or(...)Contains(...)...
```

That should work, but what if I want to match word `loe` to all columns (fe. `9`)? is that a proper way ? or maybe I should create a `@Query` for that reason ?

Comment: You mean to say, get the row(s) only if word `loe` is contained in all the columns of that row(s)?

Comment: I mean making a search phrase. I have a word `loe` and it should return users that have it in one of the three columns. So f.r. `Cloe`, `Bloe`,`loe`, `Cloes`. To be `select * from user where first_name LIKE %loe% or last_name LIKE %loe% or middle_name LIKE %loe%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `@Query` and meet your requirement. But you may want to consider using `Spring Data JPA with Specifications` and might be a better fit as this will reduce number of query methods in you repo and allows for reusable Predicates.

You just need to implement `Specification` interface and implement the method `toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery query, CriteriaBuilder cb)` to construct and return the `Predicate` that satisfies your criteria. Make the repo extend `JpaSpecificationExecutor`. The good thing is these `Predicates` are reusable and you can compose them further as you want.

You can go through [Advanced Spring Data JPA - Specifications and Querydsl](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) to get an overview.

To simplify the code further, to avoid coding `Specification`, you may want to check `Spring data JPA QueryDsl` as well.